# Java 8 CompletableFuture.thenApply()

Tags: java-8, completable-future

Finally playing around with the CompletableFuture dealio in Java 8. I'm getting a compilation error (in my IDE) that I don't really understand.

I've got a `List<String>` of identifiers that I want to append to a URL and then asynchronously call each url. So far I just have these couple methods.

```
private void process(List<String> identifiers) {

    List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = identifiers.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture.thenApply(this::sendRequest))
            .collect(toList());   
}

private void sendRequest(String s) {
        // do some URL building and append the string to the end of the url.
        // then call it, don't care about result yet
}
```

The compiler error I'm getting is on the `this::sendRequest` piece in the first method. It's complaining my class doesn't define a `sendRequest(Object)` method.

But I thought by typing the `identifiers` I didn't need to worry about calling out types in my lambda notation? I'm not even sure how to specify a type with the `::` operator. Maybe I shouldn't even be using the `::` operator? I'm confused.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.thenApply` I'm unaware of a static `thenApply` method.

Comment: Sad thing is I even pulled up the javadoc for CompletableFuture and didn't notice that. Probably on account of trying to learn lambda functions and CompletableFutures at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thenApply` must be called on an already existing `CompletableFuture` object. For example,

```
List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = identifiers.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)  // makes CompletableFuture<String>
        .map(f -> f.thenApply(this::sendRequest))
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I guess, this still doesn’t match the OP’s intention as it would be pointless to use `CompletableFuture` at all, if everything is performed within the initiator thread. Using `thenApplyAsync` rather than `thenApply` could solve this but note that `sendRequest` doesn’t return a value so it won’t work that way, using `thenAcceptAsync` instead would allow invoking a `void` method but than, the resulting `CompletableFuture` won’t return the original `String` as result…

Comment: @Holger I might be using `CompletableFuture` wrong as I don't care about the return value. I just want to see the threads work. I'll probably just do a `println` in the `sendRequest` method. I don't want it to be completely academic however as I want what I learn to translate smoothly to an actual solution. I think @Misha answered it enough to help me grasp the fundamentals and your comment cemented it.

Comment: I've done something like this `List<CompletableFuture<Void>>` I'll see how it goes.

Comment: If you don't care about the return value, using `thenAcceptAsync` and `List<CompletableFuture<Void>>` could work. An alternative to Misha's answer could be something like `identifiers.stream() .map(id -> CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> sendRequest(id) )) .collect(toList());` You could also replace `.collect(toList())` with `.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)` and pass it to `CompletableFuture.allOf`...